# How to define a polynomial/function from an array of coefficients?

Tags: function-construction, polynomials

I have the coefficients of my desired polynomial in an array CoefArr (I'm new to mathematica, so I think of everything as arrays, it is actually a list I believe) starting with the constant at index 1.

I want to turn this into a function I can evaluate like this:

```
f[x_] := CoefArr[[1]][[1]] + x*CoefArr[[2]][[1]] + etc.
```

So I can just do f[5] and get the answer. Is there a way to do this in general?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A bit more succint syntax you can reach with `Dot`, first define an array :

```
n = 10;  (*choose the length of array if not defined*)
coeffArr = RandomInteger[10, n]
```

> ```
> {2, 3, 10, 10, 9, 4, 9, 4, 6, 10}
> ```

and the result (since `Power` is `Listable`)

```
x^Range[0, n - 1].coeffArr
```

> ```
>  2 + 3 x + 10 x^2 + 10 x^3 + 9 x^4 + 4 x^5 + 9 x^6 + 4 x^7 + 6 x^8 + 10 x^9
> ```

alternatively `x^(Range[n] - 1).coeffArr`

```
% // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works if you do
    x^Range[0, n - 1].coeffArr

Comment: @Gest Now you've got what you wanted, `Plus` is `Listable` too.

Answer (score 10):

If you have an array of polynomial coefficients, you can use `FromDigits[]` in a most unconventional role:

```
coeffs = Range[10];
g[x_] = Expand[FromDigits[coeffs, x]]
   10 + 9 x + 8 x^2 + 7 x^3 + 6 x^4 + 5 x^5 + 4 x^6 + 3 x^7 + 2 x^8 + x^9
```

You could also use `Fold[]` to implement Horner's method, if you wish:

```
g[x_] = Expand[Fold[(#1 x + #2) &, 0, coeffs]]
```

Comment: (Use `Reverse[]` if you have a different arrangement of the coefficients, of course.)

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing the following from @Artes

```
n = 10;  
coeffArr = RandomInteger[10, n]
```

> {3, 9, 4, 8, 2, 5, 1, 5, 7, 3}

you can use the undocumented

```
Internal`FromCoefficientList[coeffArr, x]
```

to get

> 3 + 9 x + 4 x^2 + 8 x^3 + 2 x^4 + 5 x^5 + x^6 + 5 x^7 + 7 x^8 + 3 x^9

Comment: (+1)  Another undocumented function, very neat! :-)

Comment: @E.Chan-López thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 1):

For reference, here's the obvious solution to generate a univariate polynomial of degree $n-1$, where your coefficients are in `coeff` list of length `n`:

```
Sum[coeff[[i]] x^(i-1), {i, 1, n}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Grabbing the @bmf's list and using `FromCoefficientRules`:

```
list = {3, 9, 4, 8, 2, 5, 1, 5, 7, 3};

coeffRules = Thread[List /@ Range[Length@# - 1, 0, -1] -> #] &;

FromCoefficientRules[coeffRules@#, x] &@list

(*3 + 7 x + 5 x^2 + x^3 + 5 x^4 + 2 x^5 + 8 x^6 + 4 x^7 + 9 x^8 + 3 x^9*)
```