# How do I convert Subscript[{4, 5, 1}, 7] to the integer 4*1 + 5*7 + 1*7^2 = 88?

Tags: list-manipulation, finite-fields

I am working with the finite fields package in *Mathematica* 9.  If I input:

```
GF[7, {-2, 0, 0, 1}][{3, 4, 1}]^2
```

*Mathematica* gives me $\{4,5,1\}_7$. I want to convert this "field element" to the integer $88$, according to $4\times7^0+5\times7^1+1\times7^2$.

Comment: Have you looked at `FromDigits[]`?

Comment: I've formatted your question.  But I suggest you add a little more info.

Comment: See @J.M. 's answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24851).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As recommended by [J. M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) use [FromDigits](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromDigits.html)

```
Needs["FiniteFields`"]

gf = GF[7, {-2, 0, 0, 1}][{3, 4, 1}]^2
```

[image]

```
FromDigits[Reverse[gf[[1]]], 7]

(*  88  *)
```

Comment: Just for fun `FromDigits[Reverse@#[[1]], #[[0, 1]]] &@gf`