# Create a polynomial of a given degree

Tags: function-construction, polynomials

In Mathematica, how can I create a polynomial function in given variables of a given degree with unknown coefficents?

That is, I am looking for a function `Poly[vars, degree]` that generates, for example, if I evaluate

```
Poly[{x, y, z}, 3]
```

I should get the polynomial

```
a + a1*x + a2*y + a3*z + a12*xy + a13*xz + a23*yz + a11*x^2 + a22*y^2 + a33*z^2
+ a112*x^2*y + a113*x^2*z + a122*x*y^2 + a133*x*z^2 + a223*y^2*z + a233*y*z^2
+ a111*x^3 + a222*y^3 + a333*z^3
```

where the variables with *a* are unknown coefficients? Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Fyi, You are missing a term. `xyz` there should be 20 terms.

Comment: Closely related [How to define a polynomial/function from an array of coefficients?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24849/how-to-define-a-polynomial-function-from-an-array-of-coefficients)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
polynomial[vars_List, n_Integer, coeff_] :=
   #.Array[coeff, Length@#] &@ DeleteDuplicates[Times @@@ Tuples[Prepend[vars, 1], n]]

Clear[a]
polynomial[{x, y, z}, 3, a]
(* a[1] + x a[2] + y a[3] + z a[4] + x^2 a[5] + x y a[6] + x z a[7]
     + y^2 a[8] + y z a[9] + z^2 a[10] + x^3 a[11] + x^2 y a[12]
     + x^2 z a[13] + x y^2 a[14] + x y z a[15] + x z^2 a[16]
     + y^3 a[17] + y^2 z a[18] + y z^2 a[19] + z^3 a[20] *)
```

Comment: I like this solution best. How would I modify it to actually have coefficients in the style "a123", as in Nasser's solution?

Comment: @Posch79. Not in a convenient way. A combination of Sumit's answer and Nasser's answer would be the way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

for a one liner

```
poly[{x_,y_,z_},n_,a_]:= Sum[a[i, j, k] x^i y^j z^k,
                              {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n - i}, {k, 0, n - i - j}]
```

Comment: The sum of the iterators should be limited to n: `{i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n - i}, {k, 0, n - i - j}`

Comment: Thanks @BobHanlon for pointing that.

Answer (score 4):

another way

```
poly[vars_List, a_, order_] := Module[{n = Length@vars, idx, z},
  idx = Cases[Tuples[Range[0, order], n], x_ /; Plus @@ x <= order];
  z = Times @@@ (vars^# & /@ idx);
  z.((Subscript[a, Row[#]]) & /@ idx)
  ]

poly[{x, y, z}, a, 3]  (*a is used for coefficient*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
poly[{x, y, z}, a, 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
poly[{x, y}, a, 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
poly[{x}, a, 4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
poly[{x, y, z, w}, a, 5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To make M display the coeffs first, use `ParameterVariables :> {a}` with `TraditionalForm` (this is for display only)

```
TraditionalForm[poly[{x, y, z}, a, 3], ParameterVariables :> {a}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ps. If you do not like to use subscripts, you can use this instead:

```
poly[vars_List, order_] := Module[{n = Length@vars, idx, z},
  idx = Cases[Tuples[Range[0, order], n], x_ /; Plus @@ x <= order];
  z = Times @@@ (vars^# & /@ idx);
  z.((ToExpression["a" <> ToString[Row[#]]]) & /@ idx)
  ]
```

and now `poly[{x, y, z}, 3]` gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers thus far used one of my favorite *Mathematica* functions. Thus,

```
With[{vars = {x, y, z}, deg = 3},
     Sum[With[{fs = FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1, Length[vars]], k]}, 
              Inner[#2^#1 &, fs, vars, Times].(C @@@ fs)], {k, 0, deg}]]
   C[0, 0, 0] + z C[0, 0, 1] + z^2 C[0, 0, 2] + z^3 C[0, 0, 3] + y C[0, 1, 0] +
   y z C[0, 1, 1] + y z^2 C[0, 1, 2] + y^2 C[0, 2, 0] + y^2 z C[0, 2, 1] + y^3 C[0, 3, 0] +
   x C[1, 0, 0] + x z C[1, 0, 1] + x z^2 C[1, 0, 2] + x y C[1, 1, 0] + x y z C[1, 1, 1] + 
   x y^2 C[1, 2, 0] + x^2 C[2, 0, 0] + x^2 z C[2, 0, 1] + x^2 y C[2, 1, 0] + x^3 C[3, 0, 0]
```

---

If subscripts are preferred:

[image: but I don't really prefer them at all]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `((Subscript[a, Row[#]])&/@idx)` or `((ToExpression["a"<>ToString[Row[#]]])&/@idx)` or `Array[coeff, Length@#] or a[i, j, k]` it is possible to simply use

```
Unique["a"]
```

to get nice simple unique coefficient names.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use [`FromCoefficientRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromCoefficientRules.html) and [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed.html).

```
ClearAll[poly];
poly[coeff_Symbol, vars_?VectorQ, order_Integer?Positive] :=
 FromCoefficientRules[
  Flatten@MapIndexed[#2 - 1 -> Indexed[coeff, #2] &, 
    ConstantArray[0, ConstantArray[order + 1, Length@vars]], {Length@vars}],
  vars]
```

`poly` builds a list of [`CoefficientRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientRules.html) using `Indexed` of the undefined symbol `coeff` to represent the coefficients. It has to use `order + 1` to add space for the powers of zero since *Mathematica* starts counting indices at 1.

The main benefit of this method is the you can control all the coefficients through one variable and the polynomial updates automatically.

Picking a small polynomial as an example.

```
ClearAll[a, x, y];
p = poly[a, {x, y}, 2]
```

$x^2 y^2 a_{3 3}+x^2 y a_{3 2}+x^2 a_{3 1}+x y^2 a_{2 3}+x y a_{2 2}+x a_{2 1}+y^2 a_{1 3}+y a_{1 2}+a_{1 1}$

Because `Indexed` was used we can now set `a` to a $3 \times 3$ matrix (constants plus the two variables) and `p` will update.

```
SeedRandom[123];
a = RandomInteger[5, {3, 3}];
p
```

$3 x^2 y^2+2 x^2 y+5 x y+2 x+y^2+5 y+3$

You can change any coefficient in `a` and `p` will update. Here, the constant is changed.

```
a[[1, 1]] = -2;
p
```

$3 x^2 y^2+2 x^2 y+5 x y+2 x+y^2+5 y-2$

You can also clear the coefficients by clearing `a` and `p` will update.

```
a =.;
p
```

$x^2 y^2 a_{3 3}+x^2 y a_{3 2}+x^2 a_{3 1}+x y^2 a_{2 3}+x y a_{2 2}+x a_{2 1}+y^2 a_{1 3}+y a_{1 2}+a_{1 1}$

Hope this helps.

Comment: This I guess demonstrates the tiny bit of friction between the choices of zero-indexing and one-indexing. :)