# Splitting a general rational polynomial ansatz into powers

Tags: simplifying-expressions, polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

**EDIT**
**This question is completely wrong and useless. It is mathematically incorrect.** I think something like `Series` is sufficient if you're trying to do something similar.

Given a general polynomial ansatz constructed using methods described in [this SE post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120841/create-a-polynomial-of-a-given-degree), which looks something like

```
 expr=(Ca1[1] + Ca1[2] x[1] + Ca1[3] x[1]^2)/(1 + Da1[2] x[1] + 
 Da1[3] x[1]^2)
```

or perhaps easier to read, I can state **my input** as

$\dfrac{c_1 + c_2x+c_3x^2}{1+d_1x+d_2x^2} . $

I am attempting to use this ansatz and attempt to solve for the various coefficients in my problem, by using `Collect`. For the case where my ansatz was simply a polynomial, this was trivial to use.

I think it might be useful to instead attempt to separate this out into a polynomial in powers of `x` immediately. In particular, for one free variable `x` and only up to order two in the polynomial, I am expecting to find the result (in more legible notation).

$c_1 + c_2x+c_3x^2 +
\\
 \dfrac{c_1}{d_1} \dfrac{1}{x}  +  \dfrac{c_2}{d_1} + \dfrac{c_3}{d_1}x + 
\\
\dfrac{c_1}{d_2} x^2  +  \dfrac{c_2}{d_2}x + \dfrac{c_3}{d_2} 
$.

Importantly, I then want to collect into relevant powers of `x` and solve for the coefficients, probably using `Collect` to collate the corresponding powers. Below I have stated my **desired output**.

$ (c_1 + \dfrac{c_2}{d_1} + \dfrac{c_3}{d_2}) + (c_2 + \dfrac{c_3}{d_1}+ \dfrac{c_2}{d_2})x + (c_3 + \dfrac{c_1}{d_2})x^2  + \dfrac{c_1}{d_1} x^{-1} + \dfrac{c_1}{d_2} x^{-2} $

I attempted to do this using replacement rules, like

```
expr//.{a__/(b_+c_):>a/b+a/c,(a_+b_)/c_:>a/c+b/c}
```

and then collect appropriately, but it ended up giving me a very weird form which wasn't useful to me. Any suggestions would be appreciated. As a summary, I am hoping to take a rational function of polynomials, and simplify the out to look more like a power series in orders of x, as described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to get your desired output (with typos corrected) use

```
s = (c1 + c2 x + c3 x^2)/{1, d1 x, d2 x^2} // Total;
d = (c1 + c2/d1 + c3/d2) + (c2 + c3/d1) x + c3 x^2 + (c1/d1 + c2/d2)/x + c1/d2 x^(-2);
```

and `s == d // Simplify` will confirm that they are the same.

However this desired output **is not** equivalent to the rational function because division **does not** distribute.

Comment: Much more compact: `PadeApproximant[1 + 2 x + 3 x^2 + 4 x^3 + 4 x^4, {x, 0, 2}]`

Comment: Hi Somos; thank you for your answer. It doesn't quite run correctly on my system, and I get an error which I'm not expecting. If I change a few things (like putting a zero instead of O?), then I can get a solution, but it's still not the result which you state. Either way, I don't quite see how this solves my problem I'm afraid.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't quite run correctly on my system"? Try a new Mathematica session. SInce you did not give an actual example of your problem, I could not be more specific.

Comment: As in, I get an error about SeriesData, and either way, `Solve` would only find an expression for d1. I copied and pasted your code into a new session with a fresh kernel. In terms of the problem I posed, I was more looking for a method to rewrite a rational function in terms of orders of the variable `x`. I will edit my question and try and clarify.

Comment: @Brad, so you want something like a Laurent series expansion?

Comment: @Brad Sorry about my typo. In version 10 `O[x^5]` worked but it should have been `O[x]^5` and newer versions of Mathematica are more strict.

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive I guess I do - I considered it more algebraic simplification rather than anything else!

Comment: @Somos Ah, thank you for the clarification; it now runs perfectly! I'm still unsure how one might use this to rewrite the expression in my desired way (which was the main point of my question, and may have been unclear). Thank you for your answer regardless either way, and if my edit has been more useful, then I would certainly appreciate any more guidance.

Comment: @Somos thank you for your edit. I was hoping for something which would almost automate this process, for any rational function of any degree etc. Naturally, my last point of attack would be to type it manually! But you're absolutely, there's no sense in doing that at all; now that I think of it, I don't even know what I was thinking. Cup of coffee methinks...