# Create a general polynomial function

Tags: polynomials, coefficients

I search for a simple procedure to create a polynomial function with unknown coefficients.

For example if I asked for the most general polynomial of two variables 'x' and 'y', of second degree, it would be:

```
p[0] + p[1] x + p[2] y + p[3] x y + 
  p[4] x^2 + p[5] y^2
```

Are there any built-in functions that can help me achieve this goal?

Comment: Does [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120841/58370) answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, maybe?:

```
vars = {x, y};
deg = 3;
ca = Table[Array[p, ConstantArray[Length@vars, d]], {d, 0, deg}] /. 
   p[idcs__] /; ! OrderedQ[{idcs}] :> 0;  (* remove redundant coefficients *)
Fold[#2 + Dot[#1, vars] &, Reverse@ca] // Expand
(*
p[] +
 x p[1] + y p[2] +
 x^2 p[1, 1] + x y p[1, 2] + y^2 p[2, 2] +
 x^3 p[1, 1, 1] + x^2 y p[1, 1, 2] + x y^2 p[1, 2, 2] + y^3 p[2, 2, 2]
*)
```

See [`CoefficientArrays`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientArrays.html) from which this reverse process (c.a.s -> poly) is derived.

Comment: For large degree polynomials, one might prefer sparse arrays for the coefficients: `ca = Table[
  If[d == 0, p[],
   SparseArray[
    idcs : ConstantArray[_, d] /; OrderedQ[idcs] :> p @@ idcs, 
    ConstantArray[Length@vars, d]]
   ], {d, 0, deg}]`